# Confused about how HashMap works on a low level

Tags: java, c, arrays

I know HashMaps work by obtaining the hashcode of an object and then looking it up in an array. What I'm confused about is how the underlying array actually works.

Let's say, for demo purposes, the hashcode of an particular object called ObjectA is 3. Does that mean if I add it to a HashMap that the HashMap has an array with at least 4 elements? Arrays have a fixed size, so if I add an object to the same HashMap that has a hashcode of 6, does the array have to be rebuilt to have 6 values? Example:

```
hashmapArray[0] = null
hashmapArray[1] = null
hashmapArray[2] = null
hashmapArray[3] = ObjectA
```

Comment: You typically take the remainder of the hashcode modulo the array size as the index of the bucket.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table doesn't have enough information?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Dynamic_resizing

Comment: Take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11596549/how-does-javas-hashmap-work-internally).

Answer (score 1):

Here are the internals of hashmap and how it's size is changed as part of inserts:

```
java.util.HashMap.java

/**
 * The default initial capacity - MUST be a power of two.
 */
static final int DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY = 16;

/**
 * The load factor used when none specified in constructor.
 */
static final float DEFAULT_LOAD_FACTOR = 0.75f;
```

It says default size of an array is 16 and load factor means whenever the size of the hashmap reaches to 75% of its current size, i.e, 12, it will double its size by recomputing the hashcodes of existing data structure elements.

```
java.util.HashMap.java

/**
 * The maximum capacity, used if a higher value is implicitly specified
 * by either of the constructors with arguments.
 * MUST be a power of two <= 1<<30.
 */
static final int MAXIMUM_CAPACITY = 1 << 30;
```

It says the maximum size to which hashmap can expand, i.e, till 2^(30) = 1,073,741,824

Hence to avoid rehashing of the data structure as elements grow it is the best practice to explicitly give the size of the hashmap while creating it.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is slightly off, resulting in your confusion: there is an array of arrays, and the hashcode is used to index into the outer one. The inner array, the one that contains your objects, is just filled up like a list as more objects arrive which are destined for the same bucket (that's the name for the outer array).

Comment: The 2nd one is more commonly a list than an array.

Comment: Actually,  HashMap, without doubt the most important hash table implementation for Java, uses just a single array for all buckets. Source? OpenJDK source code.

Comment: Single array is a different method altogether!

Comment: No, conceptually it's an array of arrays, just like in C. Reason: it is more optimal to allocate and dereference a single block on the heap.

Comment: I thought you meant in case of collision the item goes in the next bucket